# Show Scrollbar when Scrolling in latest Chrome version (59.0.X)

Tags: css, google-chrome

Scroll bar is not visible in latest chrome browser when you scroll on a page or div. How can I make sure scrollbar to be visible when I am scrolling like other browser Firefox & Safari.

P.S.: I am using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.109

Comment: Sounds like a local issue. Does this occur in a project you're working on or with every website? If it's the first option please add the relevant code. If it's the second issue then this is off-topic.

Comment: It occurs with all the fixed height div with scroll enabled and for same page scrolling also.